# Unable To Stop Loop In Project Source Code

Tags: python, string, pandas, loops, smtp

I am building a custom email sender in Python, using sample csv data as input. I have finished most of the script, however the only issue I am having is in the last few lines of code. If you run the code (make sure to include your email/pwd) you will notice that custom emails get sent to the right recipients, however they receive multiple copies due to the loop.

I have tried a simple break statement at the end and that just sends out the first email then stops. Also haven't been able to find a solution on google/youtube.

```
import datetime
import smtplib
import os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import pandas as pd

host = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 587
usr = os.environ.get("EMAIL_USER")
pwd = os.environ.get("EMAIL_PASS")
from_email = usr


class MessageUser():
    user_details = []
    messages = []
    email_messages = []
    base_message = "Hi {name}!\n\nThank you for the purchase on {date}. We hope you are exited about using it. Just as a reminder the purchase total was ${total}. Have a great day!"
    def add_user(self, name, amount, email=None):
        name = name[0].upper() + name[1:].lower()
        amount = f"{amount}"
        detail = {
            "name": name,
            "amount": amount,
        }
        today = datetime.date.today()
        date_text = '{today.month}/{today.day}/{today.year}'.format(today=today)
        detail['date'] = date_text
        if email is not None:   # if email != None
            detail["email"] = email
        self.user_details.append(detail)
    def get_details(self):
        return self.user_details
    def make_messages(self):
        if len(self.user_details) > 0:
            for detail in self.get_details():
                name = detail["name"]
                amount = detail["amount"]
                date = detail["date"]
                message = self.base_message
                new_msg = message.format(
                    name=name,
                    date=date,
                    total=amount
                )
                user_email = detail.get("email")
                if user_email:
                    user_data = {
                        "email": user_email,
                        "message": new_msg
                    }
                    self.email_messages.append(user_data)
                else:
                    self.messages.append(new_msg)
            return self.messages
        return []
    def send_email(self):
        self.make_messages()
        if len(self.email_messages) > 0:
            for detail in self.email_messages:
                user_email = detail['email']
                user_message = detail['message']
                try:
                    email_conn = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
                    email_conn.ehlo()
                    email_conn.starttls()
                    email_conn.login(usr, pwd)
                    the_msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
                    the_msg["Subject"] = "Billing Update"
                    the_msg["From"] = from_email
                    the_msg["To"] = user_email
                    part_1 = MIMEText(user_message, "plain")
                    the_msg.attach(part_1)
                    email_conn.sendmail(from_email, [user_email], the_msg.as_string())
                except smtplib.SMTPException:
                    print("Error sending message.")
            return True
        return False

df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv')

Name = df.Name
Amount = df.Price
Email = df.Email

for name, amount, email in zip(Name, Amount, Email):
    obj = MessageUser()
    obj.add_user(f'{name}', f'{amount}', email=f'{email}')
    obj.get_details()
    obj.send_email()

# Works but need loop break suggestion.
```

```
# Previous attempt with error. email.errors.HeaderParseError: header value appears to contain an embedded header.

name = df.Name[1:]
amount = df.Price[1:]
email = df.Email[1:]

obj = MessageUser()
obj.add_user(f'{name}', f'{amount}', email=f'{email}')
obj.get_details()
obj.send_email()
```

Expected: Send custom emails to all recipients once.
Actual: Custom emails are received multiple times due to ending loop.

Comment: I do not believe it's an issue on the loop. Are you certain that all of the emails in the `.csv` file is unique? You are better off reorganizing your class and checking for duality.

Comment: Also, just for reference sake since I assume you are a beginner. You can pass parameters straight into the function without the need for `f-strings` (`obj.add_user(name=name, amount=amount, email=email)`). Also, note that `obj.get_details()` is really not doing anything in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is that your `.csv` file has repeated users/emails. You should perhaps look into structuring your code a little bit better to be able to debug it more easily.

In essence, you want to ensure you are decoupling functionalities so that you can test each one individually, so scenarios like these do not occur. Take the following, as an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

class User:
    def __init__(self, email, name, price):
        self.email = email
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def send_email_to_user(self):
        """ Sends email to the user. """
        SendEmail.send_email(self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """ Checks the equality of User by the standard == notation. """
        if (
            self.email == other.email
            and self.name == self.name
            and self.price == self.price
        ):
            return True
        else:
            return False


class SendEmail:
    @staticmethod
    def create_message(user):
        """ Creates the message template to be sent. """

        return f"<b>{user.name}: {user.email} for {user.price}</b>"

    @staticmethod
    def send_email(user):
        """ Sends email to passed user. """

        name = user.name
        email = user.email
        price = user.price

        message = SendEmail.create_message(user)

        print(f"Sending the message {message} to the user.")


data = {
    "name": ["name1", "name2", "name1", "name3"],
    "email": ["email1", "email2", "email1", "email3"],
    "price": ["$1", "$2", "$1", "$3"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

users = []
for name, email, price in zip(df.name, df.email, df.price):
    user = User(name, email, price)

    # We are using the __eq__ method here when we do "user not in users".
    if user not in users:
        users.append(user)
    else:
        print(
            f"It seems the user with the name {name} is already in the list of users."
        )

for user in users:
    user.send_email_to_user()
```

Above outputs:

```
It seems the user with the name name1 is already in the list of users.
Sending the message <b>email1: name1 for $1</b> to the user.
Sending the message <b>email2: name2 for $2</b> to the user.
Sending the message <b>email3: name3 for $3</b> to the user.
```

Notice how the code above decouples our functionalities. This way, we can more easily test whether or not we can send and template the emails (via the `SendEmail` object), and of course, eventually, send the email out to the users via the `Users` class.

Comment: Thank you @Felipe Faria for the comment. I am looking to however send to a list of potentially 100s or 1000s of emails so inputting data each time would be inefficient. This is why I was interested in an f string however it doesn't seem to function properly when i run it. I don't have any duplicates as you previously mentioned as I only have 3 lines in my sample csv and they are all different. As I haven't found a looping solution, I am going to have to utilize obj.add_user for each email. I still am not sure how I will change a value such as 0 to 1 as a loop, but perhaps regex. Thx again.

Comment: this is what I will need a solution for. Please let me know if you have an idea how to complete in scale.

Comment: obj.add_user(df.Name[0], df.Price[0], email=df.Email[0])
obj.add_user(df.Name[1], df.Price[1], email=df.Email[1])
obj.add_user(df.Name[2], df.Price[2], email=df.Email[2])
obj.add_user(df.Name[3], df.Price[3], email=df.Email[3])
obj.add_user(df.Name[4], df.Price[4], email=df.Email[4])
obj.add_user(df.Name[5], df.Price[5], email=df.Email[5])

Comment: In the code above I am still using the `pd.DataFrame(data)` and looping through it, so there shouldn't be a need to add each individual `df.Price[1]` , `df.Price[2]` , ... and so on.

Comment: I am afraid I am confused. You only have 3 rows in your `.csv` file? What is your intended goal -- to send individual emails to each email, or to send multiple emails to one email?

Comment: Also, for the case of f-strings, notice that if `a = "hey"`, then `a == f"{a}" == "hey"` is True.